# Is there any longer such a thing as a nonvolatile RAM based storage device (not flash)?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, drive

There used to be such things, rare though they were. For instance I recall there was a CompactFlash static RAM card. But surely somebody still makes a battery-backed SRAM or DRAM based PCI card based drive?

---

Ooops never mind, I see they still exist. 8MB = $250. Yikes.

Comment: Are you asking out of curiosity or because you actually have a practical application for such a whimsical piece of hardware?

Comment: http://www.storagesearch.com/ssd-ram.html

Comment: I have a practical need: I want performance, plus a few gigs of storage space, and when power is lost suddenly (and it will) I need to make sure my data isn't lost.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are still around, but they are so small it's ridiculous. RAM is cheap and you load the system up with it and flush to disk for backup. If you need performance, you get it other ways, maybe stripping to a couple SSD's. RAM for speed, disk for size, SSD for in between, mix and match for best of both worlds. What exactly would you do with such a thing?

Comment: But with flash there's a limit on the number of writes before the disk sector goes bad. What if I need to write to it continuously for months on end?

Comment: I would say that's what RAM is for.

Comment: Agreed, but the cost of PCMCIA SRAM is prohibitive. I need gigs of it, not megabytes. Hasn't anyone come up with a battery-backed PCI card with DRAM on it and a controller to refresh it?

Comment: Why can't you use regular RAM and flush it to disk periodically for safekeeping?

Comment: Because a server crash could happen at any time and the data loss would be very costly e.g. suppose I write every 10 seconds, I could lose up to 9.99 seconds of valuable data.